# Youtube Data API V3 returning ssl.SSLWantWriteError: The operation did not complete (write) error

Tags: python, pycharm, youtube-data-api

I asked almost the same question earlier, but failed to get a solution to it due to a new error that appeared while trying to solve that, which overshadowed the initial one. The problem is that when I try to upload a youtube video using the code below, I get the error in the title (full trace below) and am unable to do so. I am clueless as to what is causing the error and would appreciate any and all help.

```
def upload(beatName, mainArtist, keywords, oneLiner):

    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
    API_NAME = 'youtube'
    API_VERSION = 'v3'
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube']

    service = Create_Service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)

    upload_date_time = DT.datetime(2020, 9, 3, 12, 30, 0).isoformat() + '.000Z'

    title = "OTOROSHI - "test"
    description = 'Test'

    request_body = {
        'snippet': {
            'categoryI': 10,
            'title': title,
            'description': description,
            'tags': keywords
        },
        'status': {
            'privacyStatus': 'private',
            'publishAt': upload_date_time,
            'selfDeclaredMadeForKids': False,
        },
        'notifySubscribers': True
    }

    mediaFile = MediaFileUpload('E:\Everything.mp4')

    response_upload = service.videos().insert(
        part = 'snippet,status',
        body = request_body,
        media_body = mediaFile
    ).execute()
```

```
client_secret.json-youtube-v3-(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube'],)
['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube']
youtube service created successfully
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/ricsi/Desktop/Automatic Uploader/main.py", line 34, in <module>
     AutomaticUploader().run()
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Uploader\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 950, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Uploader\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 573, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Uploader\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 347, in mainloop
     self.idle()
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Uploader\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 391, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Uploader\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 342, in dispatch_input
     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Uploader\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 248, in post_dispatch_input
     listener.dispatch('on_motion', etype, me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Uploader\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1412, in on_motion
     self.dispatch('on_touch_down', me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Uploader\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1428, in on_touch_down
     if w.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Uploader\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 545, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Uploader\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 545, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Uploader\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 151, in on_touch_down
     self.dispatch('on_press')
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 705, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1248, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1132, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Uploader\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 57, in custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Desktop\Automatic Uploader\automaticuploader.kv", line 53, in <module>
     on_press: root.upload()
   File "C:/Users/ricsi/Desktop/Automatic Uploader/main.py", line 27, in upload
     upload(beatName, mainArtist, keywords, oneLiner)
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Desktop\Automatic Uploader\youtube.py", line 228, in upload
     response_upload = service.videos().insert(
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Uploader\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 134, in positional_wrapper
     return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Uploader\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 892, in execute
     resp, content = _retry_request(
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Uploader\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 204, in _retry_request
     raise exception
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Uploader\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 177, in _retry_request
     resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Uploader\lib\site-packages\google_auth_httplib2.py", line 200, in request
     response, content = self.http.request(
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Uploader\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1985, in request
     (response, content) = self._request(
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Uploader\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1650, in _request
     (response, content) = self._conn_request(
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Uploader\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1558, in _conn_request
     conn.request(method, request_uri, body, headers)
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Uploader\lib\http\client.py", line 1255, in request
     self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Uploader\lib\http\client.py", line 1301, in _send_request
     self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Uploader\lib\http\client.py", line 1250, in endheaders
     self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Uploader\lib\http\client.py", line 1049, in _send_output
     self.send(chunk)
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Uploader\lib\http\client.py", line 971, in send
     self.sock.sendall(data)
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Uploader\lib\ssl.py", line 1204, in sendall
     v = self.send(byte_view[count:])
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Uploader\lib\ssl.py", line 1173, in send
     return self._sslobj.write(data)
 ssl.SSLWantWriteError: The operation did not complete (write) (_ssl.c:2472)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Does your script succeeds when ran against the standard Python3 interpreter from your computer command line?

Comment: @stvar no, the same error persists..

Comment: But as far as I know, it worked a few day ago, right?

Comment: No. I simply managed to get through the authentication process. The uploading it self hasn't worked since the original post. The moment I came to retest it and formulate a nice answer this popped up, I haven't actually managed to upload a video successfully ever since posting the last question. @stvar

Comment: okay, thank you once again for your time @stvar ! I will try using the oauth playground and keep you updated!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220961/discussion-between-stvar-and-justadudetryingtocode).

Comment: I would like to ask you to post within the question the source code of function `Create_Service`.

Comment: Please be kind to mention somewhere within the question the version of your standard Python3 interpreter (run at the command line prompt: `python3 --version`). This would enable me to track down the exact version of the SSL implementation module -- `Modules/_ssl.c` -- that you're using. (You may remember about my intention to investigate further the issue of `ssl.SSLWantWriteError` down to the levels 2 and 3 specified by my answer below.)

Comment: At the same time -- though did not yet arrived at the inner level of `openSSL` (the library that stands at the base of Python's SSL implementation) -- please be kind to also copy-paste the entire output of the command `openssl version -a` issued at a command line prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Synopsis

The TLS/SSL errors are due to issues that may occur at one of the following levels:

1. The level of Client Application;
2. The level of Google's API Client Library and of its corresponding requisites (see them listed below);
3. The level of the Standard Python's SSL implementation ([TLS/SSL wrapper for socket objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html));
4. The level of the Operating System itself.

Addressing the OP's issues above, my recommendation is as follows:

> Tackling SSL errors at *the level of the client application*, if experiencing the kind of errors seen above, instead of *uploading video files in one go*, do use the [Resumable Upload Protocol](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/using_resumable_upload_protocol).

The employment of YouTube Data API's resumable uploading feature can be done quite easily, for both Python v2 and v3, as to be seen below.

Do note that using this feature will make the app be *more resilient to network-related errors*.

### Details

Before attempting to use the Python script quoted below, one should make sure that all of the libraries (i.e. Python packages) listed below are up-to-date. (Just issue `pip install --upgrade` on each of the named packages.)

- [Google API Client Library for Python](http://github.com/google/google-api-python-client)
  `google-api-python-client`
- [Google Authentication Library for Python: oauthlib integration](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-auth-library-python-oauthlib)
  `google-auth-oauthlib`
- [Google Authentication Library for Python: httplib2 transport](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-auth-library-python-httplib2)
  `google-auth-httplib2`
- [Google Authentication Library for Python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-auth-library-python)
  `google-auth`

Prior to modifying your app, do test that the resumable uploading feature of the API (that is the [Resumable Uploading Protocol](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/using_resumable_upload_protocol)) does indeed work without error (thus without SSL errors too).

First thing to do is to download the time-tested public Google script [upload_video.py](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/upload_video.py). (This script has an [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video) too. To obtain a self-explanatory usage information page from the script just issue it with the command line option `--help`.)

If you're running Python v3, then you'll have to patch `upload_video.py` as to be seen further below. In any case, for testing the resumable upload feature, simply issue at a command line prompt a command like:

`python upload_video.py --file your_video_file.mp4 --title '...' --description '...' --privacyStatus private`

or, by case:

`python3 upload_video.py --file your_video_file.mp4 --title '...' --description '...' --privacyStatus private`

Note that your client secrets file -- `client_secret.json` -- has to be present in the directory that hosts `upload_video.py`.

Upon running successfully `upload_video.py`, do check the newly uploaded video on (and eventually remove it from) your own YouTube Studio page at:

`https://studio.youtube.com/channel/YOUR_CHANNEL_ID/videos/upload`.

If everything worked OK -- no SSL errors --, then you may proceed refactoring your own code such that it to include the Python code in `upload_video.py` according to your needs.

### Patching `upload_video.py`

As currently provided by Google, the script `upload_video.py` is coded in the Python v2 language; for to make it work with Python v3, do apply to it the following changes:

0. First line of this script: replace `python` with `python3` (this is not really necessary on a Windows machine);
1. Replace `import httplib` with `import http.client`;
2. Replace all occurrences of `httplib.` with `http.client.` (do note the dots there);
3. Replace all `print EXPRESSION` with `print(EXPRESSION)`;
4. Replace all `except IDENTIFIER, e` with `except IDENTIFIER as e`.

Or, otherwise, do apply the following `.patch` file to the script file:

```diff
--- upload_video.py
+++ upload_video.py
@@ -1,7 +1,7 @@
-#!/usr/bin/python
+#!/usr/bin/python3
 
 import argparse
-import httplib
+import http.client
 import httplib2
 import os
 import random
@@ -23,10 +23,10 @@
 MAX_RETRIES = 10
 
 # Always retry when these exceptions are raised.
-RETRIABLE_EXCEPTIONS = (httplib2.HttpLib2Error, IOError, httplib.NotConnected,
-  httplib.IncompleteRead, httplib.ImproperConnectionState,
-  httplib.CannotSendRequest, httplib.CannotSendHeader,
-  httplib.ResponseNotReady, httplib.BadStatusLine)
+RETRIABLE_EXCEPTIONS = (httplib2.HttpLib2Error, IOError, http.client.NotConnected,
+  http.client.IncompleteRead, http.client.ImproperConnectionState,
+  http.client.CannotSendRequest, http.client.CannotSendHeader,
+  http.client.ResponseNotReady, http.client.BadStatusLine)
 
 # Always retry when an apiclient.errors.HttpError with one of these status
 # codes is raised.
@@ -104,31 +104,31 @@
   retry = 0
   while response is None:
     try:
-      print 'Uploading file...'
+      print('Uploading file...')
       status, response = request.next_chunk()
       if response is not None:
         if 'id' in response:
-          print 'Video id "%s" was successfully uploaded.' % response['id']
+          print('Video id "%s" was successfully uploaded.' % response['id'])
         else:
           exit('The upload failed with an unexpected response: %s' % response)
-    except HttpError, e:
+    except HttpError as e:
       if e.resp.status in RETRIABLE_STATUS_CODES:
         error = 'A retriable HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s' % (e.resp.status,
                                                              e.content)
       else:
         raise
-    except RETRIABLE_EXCEPTIONS, e:
+    except RETRIABLE_EXCEPTIONS as e:
       error = 'A retriable error occurred: %s' % e
 
     if error is not None:
-      print error
+      print(error)
       retry += 1
       if retry > MAX_RETRIES:
         exit('No longer attempting to retry.')
 
       max_sleep = 2 ** retry
       sleep_seconds = random.random() * max_sleep
-      print 'Sleeping %f seconds and then retrying...' % sleep_seconds
+      print('Sleeping %f seconds and then retrying...' % sleep_seconds)
       time.sleep(sleep_seconds)
 
 if __name__ == '__main__':
@@ -150,5 +150,5 @@
 
   try:
     initialize_upload(youtube, args)
-  except HttpError, e:
-    print 'An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s' % (e.resp.status, e.content)
+  except HttpError as e:
+    print('An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s' % (e.resp.status, e.content))
```

The `.patch` file above could well be generated by Python's own tool [`2to3`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html). This tool is also able to modify `upload_video.py` in place. (For having it installed simply issue `pip install 2to3`.)

Comment: What should `import httplib2` be replaced with?