# YouTube video uploader error ssl.SSLWantWriteError: The operation did not complete (write) (_ssl.c:2472)

Tags: python, youtube

I'm a beginner programmer and I'm working on a python script to uploads videos to my YouTube channel. I'm running into an error that in beyond my understanding. Hoping someone here can help me out. I followed this video to write the script: https://youtu.be/Pr0tC-6hh44

Here is the code:
upload-video.py

```
import datetime
from Google import Create_Service
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
API_NAME = 'youtube'
API_VERSION = 'v3'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload']

service = Create_Service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)

upload_date_time = datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 25, 12, 30, 0).isoformat() + '.000Z'

request_body = {
    'snippet': {
        'categoryI': 24,
        'title': 'Test',
        'description': 'test',
        'tags': ['test','test2']
    },
    'status': {
        'privacyStatus': 'private',
        'selfDeclaredMadeForKids': False, 
    },
    'notifySubscribers': True
}

mediaFile = MediaFileUpload('output.mp4')

response_upload = service.videos().insert(
    part='snippet,status',
    body=request_body,
    media_body=mediaFile
).execute()
```

Google.py

```
import pickle
import os
import ssl
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import Flow, InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload, MediaIoBaseDownload
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request


def Create_Service(client_secret_file, api_name, api_version, *scopes):
    print(client_secret_file, api_name, api_version, scopes, sep='-')
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = client_secret_file
    API_SERVICE_NAME = api_name
    API_VERSION = api_version
    SCOPES = [scope for scope in scopes[0]]
    print(SCOPES)

    cred = None

    pickle_file = f'token_{API_SERVICE_NAME}_{API_VERSION}.pickle'
    # print(pickle_file)

    if os.path.exists(pickle_file):
        with open(pickle_file, 'rb') as token:
            cred = pickle.load(token)

    if not cred or not cred.valid:
        if cred and cred.expired and cred.refresh_token:
            cred.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
            cred = flow.run_local_server()

        with open(pickle_file, 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(cred, token)

    try:
        service = build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=cred)
        print(API_SERVICE_NAME, 'service created successfully')
        return service
    except Exception as e:
        print('Unable to connect.')
        print(e)
        return None

def convert_to_RFC_datetime(year=1900, month=1, day=1, hour=0, minute=0):
    dt = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0).isoformat() + 'Z'
    return dt
```

Here is my Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\matth\AppData\Roaming\npm\trend\upload-video.py", line 30, in <module>
    response_upload = service.videos().insert(
  File "C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 134, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 892, in execute
    resp, content = _retry_request(
  File "C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 204, in _retry_request
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 177, in _retry_request
    resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\google_auth_httplib2.py", line 200, in request
    response, content = self.http.request(
  File "C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1985, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(
  File "C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1650, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(
  File "C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1558, in _conn_request
    conn.request(method, request_uri, body, headers)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py", line 1255, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py", line 1301, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py", line 1250, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py", line 1049, in _send_output
    self.send(chunk)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py", line 971, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ssl.py", line 1204, in sendall
    v = self.send(byte_view[count:])
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ssl.py", line 1173, in send
    return self._sslobj.write(data)
ssl.SSLWantWriteError: The operation did not complete (write) (_ssl.c:2472)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please have a look at [the answer I gave to a very much related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63763037/8327971). I do think that the solution provided there is to be of help to your issue too.

Comment: Could you please edit your question adding the entire output of each of the following two commands (run them at a command line prompt): `python3 --version` and `openssl version -a`. (This info would enable me to track down this `SSLWantWriteError` issue at the levels 2 and 3 mentioned within my answer quoted above.)

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact error but it turned out to be caused by a network switch. As soon as I removed the switch (via plugging my PC directly into the router), the issue was resolved. The crazy thing was that sometimes I could still get an upload to work, but 9 times out of 10 it would fail with the error "ssl.SSLWantWriteError: The operation did not complete (write)".

Hopefully this will help someone Googling this error (and save future me some time when I inevitably forget to remove the switch after adding it back in to connect a different device to the internet).

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled across this error myself and found a fix.

For me, the first file I was trying to use was very large and the response was actually a message telling you to go to the google dev console and activate the API v3.

Only when I tried a smaller file did I actually get the notification. I was getting the operation did not complete message as you were getting.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).