# google python api problem when uploading to youtube

Tags: python-3.x, youtube-data-api

i want to automate uploading time-lapse videos to YouTube using the google API i am using the upload code found https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video when i run the python command
`python3 /home/sherio/youtube/upload.py --file="/home/sherio/youtube/bbb.mp4" --title="BBB Test upload" --description="upload test" --category="22" --privacyStatus="private"` i get the following error    `File "/home/sherio/youtube/upload.py", line 133 print "Uploading file..." ^ SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("Uploading file...")?`

can any one provide me with any advice on how to sort this issue i am frunning it on Linux Mint running python 3.8.5

Comment: Oh wow that's a really old code sample, it seems. It would work only on Python 2. You can try running a 2to3 utility on the code, or just run it on Python 2.x if you have that installed as well.

Comment: The error explains the issue. `Print` is a function in python3 so it needs parentheses.

Comment: I recommend to proceed according to the section *Patching upload_video.py* of [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63763037/8327971). Applying one of the procedures indicated there, you'll be able to run the code provided by Google on Python 3+.