# An ssl.SSLWantWriteError error on Youtube API can not work with long videos

Tags: python, error-handling, youtube-api

I want to use Youtube API to upload a video on youtube but it is not working. I read the same question [Youtube Data API V3 returning ssl.SSLWantWriteError: The operation did not complete (write) error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63710844/youtube-data-api-v3-returning-ssl-sslwantwriteerror-the-operation-did-not-compl/63763037#63763037) but it is not working with a solution on this question. But I know that If I have a 1 minute-long video is any problem here but if I have a 1 hour long video this error came.

```
File "c:/Users/Lukas/OneDrive - ZSMosBB/Dokumenty/python_scripts/AMP/video_uploads2.py", line 30, in <module>
response_upload = service.videos().insert(


File "C:\Users\Lukas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lukas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 923, in execute
    resp, content = _retry_request(
  File "C:\Users\Lukas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 222, in _retry_request
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\Lukas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 191, in _retry_request
    resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lukas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\google_auth_httplib2.py", line 218, in request
    response, content = self.http.request(
  File "C:\Users\Lukas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1725, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(
  File "C:\Users\Lukas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1441, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "C:\Users\Lukas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1364, in _conn_request
    conn.request(method, request_uri, body, headers)
  File "C:\Users\Lukas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 1255, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Lukas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 1301, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Lukas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 1250, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Lukas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 1049, in _send_output
    self.send(chunk)
  File "C:\Users\Lukas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 971, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
  File "C:\Users\Lukas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ssl.py", line 1204, in sendall
    v = self.send(byte_view[count:])
  File "C:\Users\Lukas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ssl.py", line 1173, in send
    return self._sslobj.write(data)
ssl.SSLWantWriteError: The operation did not complete (write) (_ssl.c:2473)
```

here is my code:

```
import datetime
from Google import Create_Service
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'youtube_client.json'
API_NAME = 'youtube'
API_VERSION = 'v3'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload']

service = Create_Service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)

upload_date_time = datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 25, 12, 30, 0).isoformat() + '.000Z'

request_body = {
    'snippet': {
        'categoryI': 10,
        'title': 'best music on the youtube | happy mood mix | AMP',
        'description': "test",
        'tags': ['Travel', 'video test', 'Travel Tips']
    },
    'status': {
        'privacyStatus': 'private',
        'publishAt': upload_date_time,
        'selfDeclaredMadeForKids': False, 
    },
    'notifySubscribers': False
}

mediaFile = MediaFileUpload('output.mp4')

response_upload = service.videos().insert(
    part='snippet,status',
    body=request_body,
    media_body=mediaFile
).execute()


service.thumbnails().set(
    videoId=response_upload.get('id'),
    media_body=MediaFileUpload('thumbnail.png')
).execute()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Youtube Data API V3 returning ssl.SSLWantWriteError: The operation did not complete (write) error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63710844/youtube-data-api-v3-returning-ssl-sslwantwriteerror-the-operation-did-not-compl)

Comment: Sorry but not because I used this answer in past but I still do notž know how to create a refresh token for not 24 hours because it always expires after day and I want to make an automatic upload without a day by day change a refresh token.

Comment: The access token will expire after an hour the refresh token should be good for seven days if your app is still in testing.    where is the code you are using that stores your token?